# Socket.io: How can I check to see if a certain number of clients have emitted an event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

With Socket.io, I'm querying all connected clients to get a status on whether or not they are ready to do something. Once they have all responded back, I want to emit an event.

How can I check whether or not each client has responded, assuming that I already know how many clients are connected?

Right now, the code looks like this:

```
var totalClients = 2; //countClientSockets();
var readyClients = 0;

socket.on("syncReady", function() {
        debug.log("Client is ready!");
        readyClients++;
        debug.log("Ready Clients: " + readyClients + "/" + totalClients.length);
        if (readyClients == totalClients.length) {
            debug.log("Room is synced! Sending start event...");
            io.sockets.emit("play");
        } else {
            debug.log("Room is not synced yet! Waiting...");
        }
    });
```

However, this results in the console output (after both clients have gotten ready and responded):

```
[Debug][Handler]: Client is ready!
[Debug][Handler]: Ready Clients: 1/2
[Debug][Handler]: Room is not synced yet! Waiting...
[Debug][Handler]: Client is ready!
[Debug][Handler]: Ready Clients: 1/2
[Debug][Handler]: Room is not synced yet! Waiting...
```

I would like it to output:

```
[Debug][Handler]: Client is ready!
[Debug][Handler]: Ready Clients: 1/2
[Debug][Handler]: Room is not synced yet! Waiting...
[Debug][Handler]: Client is ready!
[Debug][Handler]: Ready Clients: 2/2
[Debug][Handler]: Room is synced! Sending play event...
```

**What would be a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely have the right idea and your code is close to correct.

I'm guessing the main issue is that your `readyClients` is defined inside your `io.on('connection',function(){})` handler (not totally sure though since that part of the code isn't shown).

You want to keep that variable outside of `io.on` so that it doesn't get recreated on every connection. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var totalClients = 2;
var readyClients = 0;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on("syncReady", function() {
    console.log("Client is ready!");
    readyClients++;
    console.log("Ready Clients: " + readyClients + "/" + totalClients);
    if (readyClients == totalClients) {
      console.log("Room is synced! Sending start event...");
      io.sockets.emit("play");
    } else {
      console.log("Room is not synced yet! Waiting...");
    }   
  }); 
});
```

I also changed `totalClients.length` to `totalClients` since `totalClients` isn't an array.

Comment: This, collectively was my problem. +1

Comment: well, +1 when I have 15 rep